# CakePHP 2 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, cakephp, internal-server-error

Before moving on I want to mention that I have tried to look for answers in the web but in vain.

I am tasked with investigating why our CakePHP-based website is no longer working on our staging server. When loading the site at times it loads completely, but when logging a user in it takes forever to authenticate such that it produces an `Internal Server Error`.

Step 1: I have checked the cache directory for both persistent and models and they are clean.

Step 2: The Configure::write value for debug is already set to 2. Nothing gets written on the error.log file.

Could this have anything to do with Session data? I am trying to figure out what's going on and I have tried looking into the lib folder for Cake to see if I can edit the files in there to actually see what the website actually outputs instead of the `Internal Server Error` message. Which file should I edit in there? I followed [this](http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/341) link but it seems like the core is a different version.

Comment: Is error logging enabled? Without it you won't get anything other than a 500 ISE message and your logs will be empty.

Comment: I faced the issue before, that time problem with write permission on tmp folder, are you sure that the tmp folder is writable?

Comment: @Styphon It is as there were some few irrelevant error messages on the file before I cleared it. @ version_0.1 Yes it is according to my understanding but will double check.

Comment: I have run chmo -R a+w tmp to make sure that the directory is recursively writeable. The pages still load forever. I am thinking maybe there is a database table missing or something. I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was an issue with a SAP Server connection which kept the pages on the loop until they timeout resulting into an internal server error. This is evident of the fact that the live website was working fine.

I think the best solution would be to tweak the SAP Server connection component such that it doesn't timeout requests. As much as I lack knowledge of the technology. I have disabled the call and everything worked fine at a speed of light.